# PHP cast string to int memory usage: Should I cast string numbers to int numbers or not?

Tags: php, string, memory-management, casting, int

I get rows from a database and put them in a custom class. The rows contain (among others) the following MySQL types:

- `date`
- `int(5)`

When I get the rows, I get them as strings, e.g.:

- `'2020-03-02'`
- `'1234'`

I decided to do a little testing in memory usage. I used the PHP function `memory_get_usage`. When I save the date as timestamp, the memory usage seems to be much lower.

My question is: Should I cast all possible variables to integers in order to save memory or not? What would it do to the system, like the server's processor usage?

Comment: I would only concern myself with memory usage if the application requires optimisation.  You can slightly improve performance using the correct types, but the real villain with regards to memory allocation is likely to be caused by inefficient logic or redundancies.

Comment: A sample example from your question: `When I save the date as timestamp, the memory usage seems to be much lower`->Ok, but if you have to show it somewhere like front-end/back-end in term of a website/local/client Application. You have to convert it to date again and then it will neutralize the memory usage you save, or may be it will take more memory to do so in terms of multiple pages needs to show dates.